# How to web scrape a tree into an R list in form of a tree?

Tags: r, tree, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to web scrape the names of (Polish) [Wikipedia categories](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Drzewo_kategorii) that are given in a form of a tree into an R list, keeping the structure of a tree.

My idea was to put all the categories into a list where the sublists would indicate the subcategories of that category. The problem is I don't know how to make the scrape go into the dippest children.

What I have right now, is separate lists for certain levels of the tree but it doesn't seem to be optimal solution. In addition, I scrape for the links first and then the names of the categories doing (almost) exactly the same twice.

This is the code that I wrote so far:

```
library("stringi")
library("rvest")

find_links <- function(link){
  strona <- read_html(link)
  kategorie <- html_nodes(strona, ".CategoryTreeLabel")
  if(length(kategorie)==0) return(NA)
  as.list(stri_paste("http://pl.wikipedia.org", html_attr(kategorie, "href")))
}

find_titles <- function(link){
  strona <- read_html(link)
  kategorie <- html_nodes(strona, ".CategoryTreeLabel")
  if(length(kategorie)==0) return(NA)
  as.list(html_text(kategorie))
}

link <- 'http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Drzewo_kategorii'
strona <- read_html(link)
kategorie <- html_nodes(strona, ".CategoryTreeLabel")[-c(1:10, 14, 69, 96, 101, 155, 176, 188, 220, 234)] //don't need these categories
kategorie <- kategorie[220:225] //taking a sample so it doesn't take long
linki <- as.list(stri_paste("http://pl.wikipedia.org", html_attr(kategorie, "href")))
tytuly <- as.list(html_text(kategorie))
tytuly <- list(tytuly, linki)


aa <- rapply(linki, find_links,  how = 'replace')
aa1 <- rapply(linki, find_titles, how = 'replace')
bb <- rapply(aa, find_links,  how = 'replace')
bb1 <- rapply(aa, find_titles,  how = 'replace')
...
```

And here is the result for bb1 (the second level of the tree):

```
> bb1
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "Odznaczenia Związku Ochotniczych Straży Pożarnych Rzeczypospolitej Polskiej"


[[1]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[4]]
[[1]][[4]][[1]]
[1] "Pożary według państw"
```

Please help. I'm open to any other solution that keeps the structure of categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(stringi)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

expand_tree = function(link, level) {
  print(link)

  tree_nodes = 
    link %>%
    read_html %>%
    html_nodes(".CategoryTreeLabel")

  if (length(tree_nodes) > 0)
    data_frame(link = 
                 tree_nodes %>% 
                 html_attr("href") %>%
                 paste0("http://pl.wikipedia.org", .),
               name = html_text(tree_nodes) ) %>%
    setNames(names(.) %>% paste(level, . , sep = ".") ) else data_frame() }

level1 = 
  'http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Drzewo_kategorii' %>%
  expand_tree("level1") %>%
  slice(-c(1:10, 14, 69, 96, 101, 155, 176, 188, 220, 234)) %>%
  slice(220:225)

level2 = 
  level1 %>%
  group_by(level1.link) %>%
  do(expand_tree(first(.$level1.link), "level2")) %>%
  ungroup

level3 = 
  level2 %>%
  group_by(level2.link) %>%
  do(expand_tree(first(.$level2.link), "level3")) %>%
  ungroup
```